# How to use method of a component in another component angular 2?

Tags: angular

in Angular 2 in a header component I have signup button that if click on it a modal dialog opens. I have made its method and the other things. And in main page that it is a separate component if I click on a button(it's name is continue) I want that modal dialog open exactly when I click on signup button in header. 
I'm confused in how to use method of a component in another component?
this is header html and ts:

```
<a class="button" type="button" (click)="showDialog()" >sign up</a>
showDialog() {
this.display = true; }
```

and this is that button use in another component:

```
<button [disabled]="!propertyForm.form.valid"
                      (click)="onSubmit($event)" type="submit">continue</button>
```

thank you for your helping in a simple and easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Use your main component as a **parent** and load your second component in as a **child**.
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Parent html with your button

---

Child html (can be different childs to)